# Disable user login, register and password reset

Tags: 8, users

I am working on a Drupal 8 site that for all intents and purposes will be used as a company intranet. I'm also using the [Social Auth Google](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_auth_google) module to allow only company-registered GSuite accounts to use the site.

I have tested this module, and it works great! However, I'd like to remove the /user/login, /user/register, and /user/password routes, as well as the associated tabs (as per screenshot below), to prevent anyone using **anything but** the Google Social Auth login feature.

> [image: screenshot]

Sure, I could use CSS to *hide* these elements, but that doesn't feel right to me.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to achieve this.

Comment: how about redirecting them?

Comment: Be careful not to interfere with say, breaking UID 1 from logging in.

Comment: @Kevin: I thought about this as well, and thought of creating an unknown page and adding the User Login block into the content area of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in a custom module that we call 'custom', have custom.services.yml with content :

```
    services:
  custom.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\custom\Routing\RouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

then create the file src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php with the following :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    // Always deny access to unwanted routes.
    $disallow_routes = [
      'user.login',
      'user.register',
      'user.pass',
    ];
    foreach ($disallow_routes as $disallow_route) {
      if ($route = $collection->get($disallow_route)) {
        $route->setRequirement('_access', 'FALSE');
      }
    }
  }

}
```

enable the 'custom' module and this should work :)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, izis. I learnt something new

Comment: @izus It worked, but I do not want to disable login completely. I want to make it secure. I have installed key auth module which provides a unique key for every user. That key is used for authentication like this https://example.com/user/login?api-key=(unique_user_key) So I want to allow user to login using this link. How can I do it? If you have better suggestions, please share it with me.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable the login page with the [Disable Login Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_login) module. This will disallow accessing the login page without the required key value pair in the querystring.